# Polymorphic function in OCaml not accepting different types

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a function in OCaml to remove consecutive duplicates from any given list. I believe I have figured out the proper recursive function but when I try to test it with either an `int list` or a `string list`, it tells me that my function is expecting the type `'a list`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
let compress l =

  let rec compress_loop l cl e =

    match l with

    |[] -> cl

    |h::t -> if(h == e) then

          compress_loop t cl h

        else

          compress_loop t (List.append cl h) h 

  in

  compress_loop l [] [];;


compress ["a";"b"];;
```

Answer (score 1):

The root problem is the last argument given here: `compress_loop l [] []`. Because you pass it the empty list, `e` must be of type `'a list`. And because you compare `e` with `h` in `if(h == e) then`, `h` must also be an `'a list`. And because `h` is deconstructed from `l`, which is also a list, `l` must have the type `'a list list`.

Therefore, when you give it a `string list` the compiler will tell you it expects the elements to be of type `'a list`, not `string`.